# Negative definite forcing of an ODE ? (soft question)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, soft-question, positive-semidefinite, coercive

Given an ODE in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=b(x(t)).$$

How can the assumption that

$$\langle D b \xi,\xi\rangle \leq - c |\xi|,~~~~~\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

be interpreted? Does this stop the trajectory going too wild in some sense? What would this condition be called?  (Here $Db$ is the differential of $b$).

Comment: Is that a constant $D$ or $Db$ as in the differential of b.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza the differential of $b$

Comment: This condition on $Db$ implies that it cannot have any eigenvalues with real part $>0$. This likely stabilizes fixed points at roots of $b$, but more cannot be said in general without knowning the structure of the level set $\{x:b(x)=0\}$ and knowledge of the behavior of $b$ near this set.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that DB cannot have eigenvalues with real part $> -c$, i.e., all eigenvalues have real part $\leq -c<0$ ?
Linearizing near an equilibrium point $x

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is that $b'$ has all eigenvalues with real part $\leq -c<0$. (Presuming $c>0$ here).

Linearizing near an equilibrium point $x_0\in \{b(x) = 0\}$ and we get
$$\dot{x} = b(x_0) + b'(x_0)x + O(2) = b'(x_0)x + O(2)\ .$$
So in a neighborhood of $x_0$ our system will act like $\dot{x} = b'(x_0)x$ which is asymptotically stable. So I think that *if* for some $t_1$ $x(t_1)$ is close enough to $\{b=0\}$, it will thereafter approach a stable fixed point.

I'm unsure the conditions needed to guarantee one enters such a region of stability.